# Constant Higher-order derivatives

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives, weak-derivatives, constants

Given the equation
$$\frac{d^ky}{dx^k}=c$$
where $k$ represents the number of higher-order derivatives and $c$ represents any constant real number except $0$.

Eg :
$$\frac{d^{11}y}{dx^{11}}=100$$
Can I conclude that the curve of the function has no inflection points?

Comment: What is the general solution to $y''' = c$? What can you say about the inflection point(s) of those functions?

Comment: Hint: What differential equation does $y''$ satisfy? what kind of function will it be?

Comment: In the third derivative let's say it is a 8th degree polynomial function, eg: 4x^8 + 5x^7+.... , if the third derivative become constant , than the 4th derivaitve is 0, which we don't want as i mention c > 0.

Comment: @whpowell96 it will be a polynomial function.

Answer (score 0):

The general solutions are the polynomial of degree $k$ with leading term $\frac{c}{k!}x^k$. These polynomial can have an inflection point, but they don’t need to. There are polynomials with no inflection point and there are polynomials with inflections points.

The polynomial $p$ must have an inflection point, if it is of odd order, since then $p’’$ is a polynomial of odd degree (or the polynomial $0$), which must have a root over $\mathbb{R}$.